# How do you distinguish your public API interfaces from the interfaces you use for testing/mocking?

Tags: java, c#, unit-testing, interfaces

Mocking frameworks are useful for creating mock objects that isolate the code under test from its surrounding software environment.  Some mocking frameworks cannot mock non-virtual methods, so they require that you create an `Interface` for each class, if you don't want to make the methods `virtual`.

How do you distinguish those Interfaces from the "real" ones?  That is, if you have a public API, do you name the interfaces that you intend your customer to use something else, or do you hide the testing Interfaces in a separate assembly or namespace?

As an aside, is it really necessary to create all those Interfaces?  I don't like the idea of making all my methods `virtual`, but I *really* don't like the idea of creating that many interfaces just to make them accessible to a mocking framework.

Comment: Such a "too broad"...

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub: I don't see how.  It's not like I'm asking "what is the best way to do something," or "list all the things," or "teach me how to program."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't.

Either the class is (effectively) sealed/final or it has an interface. I don't buy the whole internal classes are somehow above the law: abstraction exists to protect you from change, and your internal types are just as likely to change.

Basic structures (DTO's, tuples, and other usually sealed/final objects) are fine in my experience to just use as is in tests. They are effectively part of the public interface of your modules.

Comment: OK, wait a minute.  Interfaces can exist for reasons beyond simply providing a testing trampoline.  They can also be used to identify an API that can have multiple underlying implementations, and for other non-trivial reasons, as you are probably already well aware.  I claim that those deserve special mention in an API, precisely because they are likely to be used by the customer (Mocks don't count as a different underlying implementation).  Nobody in their right mind would include all those interfaces in their customer documentation. (**Customer:** What are these for?)

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I concur, and in general, interfaces will be likely used by the customer. But the question indicates they won't be, and I would argue that if internal only types are beefy enough (or lie on module boundaries enough) that you _want_ to mock them, you'll inevitably want to vary underlying implementations - so might as well abstract that to an interface even if it's not customer facing.

Comment: How do you test your sealed classes if they don't have interfaces?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I just use them directly.

Comment: Hm?  How do you mock them if the methods are not virtual?

Comment: @robertHarvey - I don't. Why would I mock a Plain Old Data structure? For really basic and pervasive structures, it seems like more work than benefit to mock them _everywhere_ that uses them.

Comment: So you're saying that you only seal DTO's/POCO's/POJO's?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - and things like Java style function objects, yes. (Though Java style function objects have mockable interfaces I suppose).

Comment: I have to say, your approach seems very odd.  .NET Framework classes are sealed by default, which under your arrangement precludes testing them with mocks.